# Problem with iterating over the list of lists

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to compute a transpose of the matrix, which I have in the form of list of lists. 
The initial matrix is m*n, I have created a matrix n*m. The problem appears when I start to use the nested loop.

```
m = 0
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, columns):
        final1[j][i] = m
        print(final1)
        m += 1
```

I deliberately print the whole list of lists (final) to see how at each step my values are changing, also I just assign consequent natural numbers for simplicity.
what I see is (first 4 lines of the output)

```
[[0, None, None, None], [0, None, None, None], [0, None, None, None]]
[[1, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None]]
[[2, None, None, None], [2, None, None, None], [2, None, None, None]]
[[2, 3, None, None], [2, 3, None, None], [2, 3, None, None]]
```

So, by accessing final[j][i], at position j = 0, i = 0 the values final[1][0] and final[2][0]
are also changing. How to avoid this? and make the first 4 lines of this format:

```
[[0, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]
[[0, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]
[[0, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None], [2, None, None, None]]
[[0, 3, None, None], [1, None, None, None], [2, None, None, None]]
```

```
rows = int(input())
columns = int(input())
final1 = [[None] * rows] * columns
```

This is the way I declare final1

Comment: What is `final1`? Can you show us your initial list?

Comment: show us the declaration of final matrix please

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use libraries? Numpy can transpose a matrix. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html

Comment: @Andreas Hofmann - this could be done in 5secs with pandas, but cause i want to solve the problem the most primitive way - i dont use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the declaration statement is internally equivalent to appending a single list `([None]*rows)` `column` times into the `final1` list.

If you are familiar with [copy problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) , this is nearly the same. All the lists inside `final1` are the same lists in terms of the memory they represent.

That's why when you update a value in one list, it gets reflected to all.

**Note :** You are actually creating a list of lists with `column` number of rows and `row` number of columns.

You can solve this issue by declaring final1 this way :

```
final1 = [[None for i in range(rows)] for j in range(columns)]
```

**p.s:** I've used rows inside and columns outside just to make it as an alternative to your declaration. It still produces a list of lists with `column` number of rows and `row` number of columns

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
rows = int(input())
columns = int(input())
final1 = [[None for i in range(rows)] for j in range(columns)]

m = 0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        final1[j][i] = m
        m += 1

print(final1)
```